# C++ lambda capture list by value or by reference doesn't give me different results

Tags: c++, lambda

I am having the below code :

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> functors;

class Bar
{
    public :
        Bar(const int x, const int y):d_x(x),d_y(y){}
        
        ~Bar(){
            cout << "Destructing Bar" << endl;
        }
    
        void addToQueue()
        {
            const auto job = [=](){
                cout << "x:" << d_x << " y: " << d_y; 
            };
            functors.push_back(job);
        }
        
    private :
        int d_x,d_y;
};


void example()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    {
        shared_ptr<Bar> barPtr = make_shared<Bar>(5,10);
        barPtr->addToQueue();
    }
    cout << "Out of scope. Sleeping" << endl;
    usleep(1000);
    functors[0]();
}
```

The output is as expected :

```
Hello World
Destructing Bar
Out of scope. Sleeping
x:5 y: 10
```

I am now capturing by value, which is why I assume when the Bar object gets destroyed, I can still access its member variables. If the above is right, I am expecting the below change to give me UB:

`const auto job = [&](){`

However, I still see the same result. Why is that? Have i understood something wrong?

***EDIT*** Further on the above, what I want to understand from this example - is how can I have access to a class member variables in a lambda function even if object has been destroyed? I am trying to avoid UB and thought that passing by value is the way to go, but can't prove that the opposite isn't working.

Comment: The joy of undefined behaviour is that sometimes your code appears to work completely normally

Comment: ` usleep(1000);` - just in case: C++ is deterministic. `Bar::~Bar()` is called immediately when `barPtr` goes out of scope; there's zero delay.

Comment: @AlanBirtles but my undestanding is correct right? if i want to make sure that when Bar gets destroyed, I can see still access its member variables, passing by value should do right?

Comment: Implicit capture of `this` with `[=]` is deprecated, BTW.  Specify either `this` or `*this`

Comment: Mangle `d_x` and `d_y` in `Bar`'s destructor to get a clearer picture of what's going on.

Comment: @PaulSanders: The problem with that is that reasonable optimizers will eliminate dead code. Writing to members in a dtor is always dead code, since the members will cease to exist at the final `}`

Comment: You can't prove the *absence* of undefined behaviour by examining a program's behaviour.

Comment: @MSalters Good point.  Might work with optimisation disabled (which would then affect the way the UB code behaves!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of confusion iss probably one of the reasons why C++20 deprecated the *implicit* capture of `this` with `[=]`. You can still capture `[this]`, in which case you have the usual lifetime issues with an unmanaged pointer. You can capture `[*this]` (since C+=17), which will capture a copy of `*this` so you don't have lifetime issues.

You could also use `std::enable_shared_from_this` since you're using a `std::shared_ptr` in `example`, but that's a bit more complicated. Still, it would avoid both the copy and the UB when the lifetime issues.

Comment: Thanks.  If I know I just have those two fields that I need - can i grab a copy of them before lambda, and capture those two fields by value? Would it achieve the same? eg 
```const int x1 = d_x;const int y1 = d_y;
     const auto job = [x=x1, y=y1]()```

Comment: @ghostrider: You don't even need to make local copies before the lambda. `[x=this->d_x, y=this->d_y]` will do.

Comment: @MSalters you don't need the `this->` either (other than for clarity), even if the captured variables have the same name as the members

Comment: @AlanBirtles: I know, it's indeed for clarity. It also helps for the answer, because it shows we're capturing the value of an expression (`this->d_x`).

Answer (score 1):

In these examples you are capturing `this` and not any of the fields.
When capturing `this`, by design, it is never captured by copying the object or the fields.
The best way to capture a field by value is:

```
[field = field] () { }
```

Comment: How does this affect "capture by reference"? That's the core of this question, no exactly what is captured.

Comment: So capturing `this` could have UB even for what I am trying to do? What I am trying to do is get access to Bar's member variables, even when the object gets destructed.

Comment: @ghostrider: yes

Answer (score 1):

Both versions of your code have undefined behaviour. `barPtr` is the only owner of the `shared_ptr` so your object is destructed at the end of the scope containing `barPtr`. Executing the lambda which has captured `this` from the object in `barPtr` has undefined behaviour.

The usual way to prevent this is for the lambda to capture a `shared_pointer` from [shared_from_this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) to keep the object alive. E.g:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

std::vector<std::function<void()>> functors;

class Bar : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Bar>
{
    public :
        Bar(const int x, const int y):d_x(x),d_y(y){}
        
        ~Bar(){
            std::cout << "Destructing Bar\n";
        }
    
        void addToQueue()
        {
            auto self = shared_from_this();
            const auto job = [this, self](){
                std::cout << "x:" << d_x << " y: " << d_y << "\n"; 
            };
            functors.push_back(job);
        }
        
    private :
        int d_x,d_y;
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Bar> barPtr = std::make_shared<Bar>(5,10);
        barPtr->addToQueue();
    }
    std::cout << "Out of scope\n";
    functors[0]();
}
```

By capturing `self` the `shared_ptr` will now survive for at least as long as the lambda does.

Comment: Hmm interesting. if I know I just have those two fields that I need - can i grab a copy of them before lambda, and capture those two fields by value? Would it achieve the same? eg 
```const int x1 = d_x;const int y1 = d_y;
     const auto job = [x=x1, y=y1]()```

Comment: yes, you are taking a copy of the values so that's fine. It's only by capturing `this` by value or by capturing anything by reference that you are getting UB

Comment: you don't even need to put them in separate variables to do that or use a `shared_ptr`: https://godbolt.org/z/9sqahre7Y